# Powershell xml select node based on parent's info

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

I'm writing a powershell script where i need to get some value of a node based on the parents' info (attribute names, id's..)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GrandParent>
    <Parent id="1">
        <foo></foo>
        <bar></bar>
        <buzz></buzz>
        <Child Name="correct">
            <Content>Value1</Content>
        </Child>
        <Child Name="wrong">
            <Content>Value2</Content>
        </Child>
        <Child Name="wrong">
            <Content>Value3</Content>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent id="2">
        <foo></foo>
        <bar></bar>
        <buzz></buzz>
        <Child Name="correct">
            <Content>Value4</Content>
        </Child>
        <Child Name="wrong">
            <Content>Value5</Content>
        </Child>
        <Child Name="wrong">
            <Content>Value6</Content>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent id="3">
        <foo></foo>
        <bar></bar>
        <buzz></buzz>
        <Child Name="correct">
            <Content>Value7</Content>
        </Child>
        <Child Name="wrong">
            <Content>Value8</Content>
        </Child>
        <Child Name="wrong">
            <Content>Value9</Content>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
</GrandParent>
```

I want to get some output like:
Parent 1: value1
Parent 2: value4
Parent 3: value7

Explanation: for each Parent node i want to look at the 'Child' node with the 'Correct' name and get the value of his child

I'm looping with ForEach-Object inside a ForEach-Object, but my context '$_' always refers to the entire xml instead of the current scope:

```
$total_xml.GrandParent.Parent | ForEach-Oject {
   $_.Parent.Child | ForEach-Object{
      $_ #This refers back to the total_xml
   }
}
```

PS: I'm a newbie in Powershell scripting :(

Can someone help me out with a simple script for this?

Comment: Check out [the `-PipelineVariable` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1).  You're also looking at the wrong thing.  Your first `foreach` should be `$_.Child` because `$_` is referring to the `Parent` node and then your second `foreach` will be pointing at each `Child` node inside that `Parent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your example:

```
[xml] $xml = Get-Content -Path .\test.xml
```

You can get your desired output:

```
Parent 1: value1
Parent 2: value4
Parent 3: value7
```

Like so:

```
$Parents = @($xml.GrandParent.Parent)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Parents.Count; $i++) {
    "Parent ${i}: " + @($Parents[$i].Child).Where{$_.Name -eq 'Correct'}.Content
}
```

or using `ForEach-Object` (didn't notice the parents had ids):

```
$xml.GrandParent.Parent |
    ForEach-Object {
        "Parent $($_.id): " + @($_.Child).Where{$_.Name -eq 'Correct'}.Content
    }
```

Comment: @JavascriptDeveloper That is just explicit so I can use the `Where` array method.  You can alternatively pass the object to `Where-Object` in a pipeline to be filtered: `$_.Child | Where-Object Name -eq 'Correct'`

Answer (score 0):

This is not best practice, but i like it because it is easily readable.

```
$xml = new-object -typename xml
$xml.Load("C:\temp\le.xml")
#To get stuff
$xml.GrandParent.Parent | Where-Object {$_.id -like 1}
#To edit stuff
($xml.GrandParent.Parent | Where-Object {$_.id -like 1}).foo = "test"
#To save stuff
$xml.Save("C:\temp\le.xml")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: hmm any suggestions?

Comment: @Xiakit the suggestion is: add additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem. That applies to all the answers you provide (as a best practice)